# Using Listview to insert an image in one column and write in another in vb

Tags: vb.net, image, winforms, listview

I have a listview with three column named: picture, time, description.
I need to add an image to the first column and at then add time and description to the other but in the same row.

I had a look on the internet and managed to find a code that adds the images to the listview. This is shown below:

```
Dim imagelist As ImageList = New ImageList()
imagelist.ImageSize = New Size(10, 10)

imagelist.Images.Add(Bitmap.FromFile("0.png"))
imagelist.Images.Add(Bitmap.FromFile("1.png"))
imagelist.Images.Add(Bitmap.FromFile("2.png"))
imagelist.Images.Add(Bitmap.FromFile("3.png"))
imagelist.Images.Add(Bitmap.FromFile("4.png"))
imagelist.Images.Add(Bitmap.FromFile("5.png"))
LV_Log.Items.Add("", 5)
LV_Log.SmallImageList = imagelist
```

Now I have a code that added text to the columns.

```
Dim lvi As New ListViewItem
lvi.Text = "image"
lvi.SubItems.Add(Now())
lvi.SubItems.Add(message)
LV_Log.Items.Add(lvi)
```

Here I want to add an image where it says "image".

Comment: Are you using WPF or WinForms?

Comment: Each ListViewItem has an ImageIndex and ImageKey which controls which if any image displays

Comment: thank You very much I just did some tests and it worked. I used the imageindex. So instead of   lvi.Text = "image" , I replaced it with lvi.ImageIndex = 2. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the ListView's imageList property is set to the correct image list you can do something like this.

```
Dim newItem As ListViewItem = New ListViewItem
newItem.ImageIndex = 0 'or look for correct one from image list
newItem.SelectedImageIndex = 0 'if the image should change
newItem.Text = Now()
newItem.SubItems.Add("description") 'may need to play here, haven't done this in a while
```

Comment: thank you very much for the help but I have figured it out using the comment from plutonix